# Get individual item count

Tags: ruby

`get_item_count` calls to an API and gets a count.  There are several pages to get this count from until there are no more results.

How do I improve this code to remove all of the extra variables and make it easier to read?

```
final_count = 0
page = 1
final_count = individual_count = get_item_count(config, page)
while individual_count > 20
  page = page + 1
  individual_count = get_item_count(config,page)
  final_count = individual_count + final_count
end
```

Comment: Do you want get_item_count() to be executed only once, that is, for page = 1 ?

Comment: Yes I do. I would prefer to only call it in once but in a loop.

Comment: Yay, I almost forgot how is it to have a feeling that it can't be cleaned, but can't come with solution in less, than 5 minutes )

Comment: Within the loop you call get_items(), but I assume you mean get_item_count(). (?)

Comment: I updated the question with the error.

Answer (score 2):

Use a do-while loop, so the loop body gets always executed at least once:

```
final_count = 0
page = 1
begin
  individual_count = get_item_count(config, page)
  final_count += individual_count
  page += 1
end while individual_count > 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Cryptic but cool way with ruby 2.0 lazy enumerators :

```
(2..Float::INFINITY).lazy
  .map {|page| get_items(config, page) }
  .take_while {|count| count > 20 }
  .reduce( get_item_count(config, 1), :+ )
# => returns final count
```

if @toto2 is right and you really mean `get_item_count` inside the loop :

```
(1..Float::INFINITY).lazy
  .map {|page| get_item_count(config, page) }
  .take_while {|count| count > 20 }
  .reduce( :+ )
# => returns final count
```

(I don't have a ruby 2 env at hand now, so didn't try but it should work)

Comment: I thought about this, but the OP seems to want the last count greater than 20, so we'd need a take_while that takes the last value.

Comment: oh, did not see that.

Comment: dang. I wish `take_while` had an :inclusive option. Some guy suggested a `take_until` that would do that.

Comment: :-) In my answer I was to suggest exactly this, either have an option or a new method. But once you have to monkeypatch the solution loses glamour. I deleted my answer because of this very thing, I couldn't get the last value without making things a lot ugglier.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to optimize is to keep the individual counts in an array and sum it up at the end.

```
count = []
until count.any? {|c| c <= 20 }
  count << get_items(config, page)
end
count.reduce(&:+)
# => returns full count
```

The whole array will be checked at each iteration. But this should not be a performance hit, especially when API communication is involved.

Comment: This wouldn't work as the `page` variable is nowhere incremented. Also, an array of counts would be better named `counts` not `count`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def final_count(config)
  fc = 0
  (1..1.0/0).each do |page|
    ic = get_item_count(config, page)
    fc += ic
    return fc if ic > 20
  end
end
```

Uncomfortable with `1.0/0`?  Then use `Float::INFINITY`.  (Edited to correct error spotted by @Rene.  Thanks, @Rene.)

Comment: The returned final count will be incorrect, as it doesn't take into account the number of items on the last page. And I'd say this solution is pushing too much towards a one-liner at the cost of readability - for example I find it weird to see a return statement inside the tertiary-operator.